# Backbone.js get previous view from collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

Now I understand this could be achieved by referencing a view from it's model. However I am attempting to stick with the "best practices" for Backbone.js where that is considered poor practice as model -> view can often be a one to many relationship.

The problem I have is this (The code samples are to help you visualise the problem):

I have an array of grouped views. Each grouped array of views contains views from multiple collections. e.g.,

```
var views; // Assume views is pre-populated with an array of views, each view's model may be stored in a different collection.

var viewGroups = _.groupBy(views, function(view) {
    return view.model.attributes.timestamp; // Unix timestamp for example
});
```

As I loop through the grouped views I need to access the views of the model that comes directly before each view's model in it's collection.

I am able to access the previous model in the collection like so:

```
_.each(viewGroups, function(viewGroup) {
    _.each(viewGroup, function (view) {
        var model = view.model;
        var collection = model.collection;
        var previousModel = collection.at(collection.indexOf(model) - 1);
    });
});
```

But because there is no affiliation from the model to it's views I am unable to find out which views subscribe to the previous model in the collection.

`var previousModelsViews = ???`

How would I do this following the design pattern that models are ignorant of views.

Comment: Do you really need to access the views, or do you want the view to execute something?

Comment: @Loamhoof I need to access the view as I need to perform DOM operations.

Comment: Then I guess you can trigger a custom event in the previous model, and make the views do their stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to know the view. Just add a custom event listener in the views:

View:

```
initialize : function(){
  this.model.on('customAction', this.customAction);
},
customAction : function(){
   //here you could do the DOM manipulation that you need on your previous view
}
```

And on your code add this:

```
var previousModel = collection.at(collection.indexOf(model) - 1);
previousModel.trigger('customAction');
```

**Update: after you updated your requirement:**
I still thinking that everything could be with events, just in the previous view dispatch other event:

View:

```
initialize : function(){
  this.model.on('customAction', this.customAction);
  this.model.on('PreviousWindowSize', this.previousSizeReceived);
},
//Previews View will arrive here 
customAction : function(nextModel){
   nextModel.trigger('PreviousWindowSize', {width: this.$el.width()});
},
//Current View will receive the size of the previous View here
previousSizeReceived : function(size){
   console.log(size);
}
```

And on your code add this(check that I added the previous model in the trigger):

```
var previousModel = collection.at(collection.indexOf(model) - 1);
previousModel.trigger('customAction', previousModel);
```

Comment: Thanks but I should of explained better, I need to get the height and position of the previous view element (Which is why I need access to the view) for use by the current view element (Why triggering an event won't work).

Comment: I updated my answer because you updated your question. I added some logic that you could use, please let me know any other doubt

Comment: Thanks for the answers that would work, however in the end I decided to take this logic out of the Backbone model / view logic as I realised a much faster approach to doing this.